# What benefits are there to using an instance variable vs passing a parameter?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

When building classes, my rule of thumb has always been to pass parameters, unless the caller has no access to them. For example, I always prefer this:

```
class Foo
{
    private FooData _data;
    public Foo(FooData data) { _data = data; }

    public string GetSomeValue()
    {
        var result = ProcessData(_data);
        return result;
    }

    private static string ProcessData(FooData data)
    {
        // do something with data and return the result
    }
}
```

Over this:

```
class Foo
{
    private FooData _data;
    public Foo(FooData data) { _data = data; }

    public string GetSomeValue()
    {
        var result = ProcessData();
        return result;
    }

    private string ProcessData()
    {
        // do something with _data and return the result
    }
}
```

I have come across the second example many times in the wild, and I have never identified a good reason. **What are the benefits and drawbacks of accessing instance variables vs. using method arguments?**

**UPDATE:** I realize that some answers to this question may be opinion based, but I am looking for things that one approach can do that the other can't so I can form my own opinion about when to use each one.

For example:

- The second method allows for shorter, more readable code.
- The first method ensures that data is not changed when processing.

Comment: Would you *ever* want to call `ProcessData` without an instance of `Foo`, or with a `FooData` which isn't the `_data` field of that `Foo`? If not, it logically acts on the instance...

Comment: Well, for one, your first example is *really hard* to follow as far as logic goes. The second example is clear that the `ProcessData` works on the data that is owned by the object.

Comment: I think the point @JonSkeet may be trying to make is why have the parameter if it won't ever be called with anything other than `Foo._data`? It also doesn't make sense to be a static method because being static doesn't buy you anything unless you can call it with other `FooData` from somewhere else.

Comment: @JonSkeet: In most cases I don't care to call ProcessData from elsewhere, but I find that the first example is easier to refactor if I ever do.

Comment: @JensEhrich if you ever have to refactor to make that happen, you've violated SOLID...

Comment: @RonBeyer: Could you elaborate on why you found the logic difficult to follow in the first example? It's clear to me, but that's probably b/c I contrived the example. Is it just the longer signatures? Also, while it doesn't buy anything, does making the method static cost anything if I don't need it to be? It's a habit of mine that forces me to use parameters instead of instance variables.

Comment: Off topic: My C# compiler (Visual Studio 2012) is not accepting "class Foo(FooData data)", it says "{ expected". Is this some new C# syntax?

Comment: I don't want to have an extended discussion in comments, but a private method acts on data the type contains. All you are doing is passing in a reference to an internal member, which won't change, so it looks odd. Its also static, which to me says "every type use this because it does something that doesn't require instance data", when you are clearly using instance data inside of it... In order to debug, you have to follow the path of data, whereas an instance method you know where it came from. Not to mention thread safety of static methods...

Comment: Another downside is debugging, when you debug the `ProcessData` method, you are in the static instance of the type, so none of the instance data is going to line up (or be valid), so `_data` in the instance type will not match `data` in the `ProcessData` method. You'll have to follow the call stack up to where it is called to see the instance data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a comprehensive argument for **preferring an instance method with no arguments**, see Robert C. Martin's [Clean Code](http://amzn.to/XCJi9X). In the *Smells and Heuristics* chapter, he clearly condenses the heuristic:

> **F1: *Too Many Arguments***
>
> Functions should have a small number of arguments. No argument is best, followed by one, two, and three.

(Page 288 in my copy.)